# R pairwise product

Tags: r, product, outer-join

I'm trying to get the pairwise products of a vector, say

```
a = c(1,2,3,4)
```

What I'm trying to get is

2,3,4,6,8,12 (in that order).

I've tried using outer:

```
outer(1:4,2:4)
```

and that gives me a matrix that includes the products I want but I'm not sure how to extract them from the matrix in a way that scales to vectors of higher dimensions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**`combn()`**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/combn.html) is nice for this sort of thing:

```
a <- 1:4

combn(a, m = 2, FUN = prod) 
# [1]  2  3  4  6  8 12
```

Comment: or `combn(1:4, 2, prod)`

Answer (score 3):

`lower.tri` selects them in that order:

```
out <- outer(1:4,1:4)
out[lower.tri(out)]
# [1]  2  3  4  6  8 12
```