# Product of every two columns (not all pairwise products)

Tags: r

This is **not** the same as [R pairwise product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899332/r-pairwise-product).

Consider the following:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = 10.3333333333333, V2 = 1.66666666666667, 
    V3 = 8.66666666666667, V4 = 2.66666666666667, V5 = 8.76666666666667, 
    V6 = 2, V7 = 6.33333333333333, V8 = 1.66666666666667, V9 = 11, 
    V10 = 2.66666666666667, V11 = 4.33333333333333, V12 = 1.66666666666667, 
    V13 = 9.83333333333333, V14 = 3.33333333333333), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", 
"V12", "V13", "V14"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

If we were treating this as a vector V, I would like to compute a vector consisting of the elements V[i] * V[i+1] for i = 1, 3, 5, ...., 13. (i.e., the first component is the product of the first two components of `df`, the second component is the product of the third and fourth components of `df`, etc.)

That is, the following produces the desired output:

```
> v <- numeric(7)
> df <- structure(list(V1 = 10.3333333333333, V2 = 1.66666666666667, 
+     V3 = 8.66666666666667, V4 = 2.66666666666667, V5 = 8.76666666666667, 
+     V6 = 2, V7 = 6.33333333333333, V8 = 1.66666666666667, V9 = 11, 
+     V10 = 2.66666666666667, V11 = 4.33333333333333, V12 = 1.66666666666667, 
+     V13 = 9.83333333333333, V14 = 3.33333333333333), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("V1", 
+ "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", 
+ "V12", "V13", "V14"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
> for (i in 1:length(v)){
+     v[i] <- df[1,2*i-1] * df[1,2*i]
+ }
> v
[1] 17.222222 23.111111 17.533333 10.555556 29.333333  7.222222 32.777778
```

Is there a way to do this **without** a loop?

Comment: Just index the even and odd entries with an integer sequence. `df[, seq(from = 1, to = ncol(df), by = 2)] * df[, seq(from = 2, to = ncol(df), by = 2)]`

Comment: @qdread Why didn't I think of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you literally what you asked for, given a `data.frame` with only one row:

```
v <- as.numeric(df[, seq(1, ncol(df), by=2)] * df[, seq(2, ncol(df), by=2)])
```

Leave out `as.numeric` to keep the result as a `data.frame`. This would work rowwise on a `data.frame` with more rows and would throw an error if the `data.frame` had an odd number of variables.

If that row of numbers were just a vector `V` as you called it, the principle is the same.

```
V <- unlist(df, recursive = TRUE, use.names = FALSE)
v <- V[seq(1, length(V), by=2)] * V[seq(2, length(V), by=2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use dplyr's lag/lead functions.  For example:

```
library(dplyr)
(df*lag(df))[,seq(2,length(df),2)]
```